# Close all files in visual studio on exit

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2005

Is there any way to close all files in Visual Studio on exit? Alternatively if that isn't possible is it possible to delete the user project file visual studio creates on exit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows->Close All Documents
File->Exit

or manually delete the .sou file after the project is close
You can probably write a VB script macro that does either of these.